# php - Image upload not working every time

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload a picture to my website but it doesn't seem to be working, instead it prints a long string of text including unrecognised characters.

**PHP code :**

```
$target_file = "path/from/webserver/Users/".$_SESSION['user']['user_code']."/background.jpg";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
if(!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"])) {
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10485760) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);  

            unlink($target_file);

            imagejpeg($image,NULL,60);
            header("Location: profile.php");
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
```

**And my HTML form is:**

*The `$t` varaible is only for the languages to work fine*

```
<form action="background.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-1px">
            <span><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></div> <?php echo $t['change_input_select'];?></span>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="upload" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $t['change_input_submit'];?>" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:-10px">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="edit_account.php" style="margin-top:-10px"><?php echo $t['change_input_abort'];?></a>
    </form>
```

Maybe you can give me some tips on how I can make this more reliable.

Comment: What "crazy long Text"? And what is found in your http servers error log file? And who is "he" in this?

Comment: Sorry but from that webhoster I can't look in the error file an the crazy long text is `ile is an image - image/jpeg.����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 60 ��C      ' .)10.)-,3:J>36F7,-@WAFLNRSR2>ZaZPJQRO��C&&O5-5OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO`and more and more

Comment: I suggest you check what is really contained in that file stored on the server side to find out what the issue is: the upload or the download. This somehow looks like some socket issue, so network related.

Comment: where is this pointing at `$target_file = "path/from/webserver/Users/"`

Comment: That is only a path that work in the other files but the image compreesing not works